# Which theorem(s) state(s) that a geodesic dome cannot be built using quads?

Tags: differential-geometry

Which theorems of Differential Geometry constitute a direct proof that a sphere cannot be tessellated using squares (or quads that aren't distorted/warped - i.e. non congruent quads)?

As a side-question, is there any trivial quad tessellation that minimizes distortion in this case?

*Tessellation* is understood in the context of computer graphics here.
[image]

Comment: I don't have time to write full answer, but the key fact that a sphere is curved and a square isn't, and that curvature can be defined in terms of derivatives of the metric, and hence, is a local isometry invariant.

Comment: hmm, does the fact that the sphere is not parallelizable or that it has positive Gauss curvature have anything to do with this? (the sphere being "curved" certainly tells it cannot be developed onto a plane, but this does not entirely explain the tessellation problem - it's not that trivial to explain to a student, for example).

Comment: When you say "tesselated using squares", do you mean pieced together out of Euclidean squares (which is impossible as Jason said), or tesselated by some notion of "squares" in spherical geometry (e.g. quads built from geodesics with equal side lengths or right angles)?

Comment: By tessellation I imply a computer graphics compatible representation of a sphere, i.e. considering a discrete sampling of its surface and drawing edges so that the resulting mesh/graph is made of quads instead of triangles or other polygons. The quads or squares have to be planar - the real requirement is for the quads to be congruent.

Comment: Isn't the cube such a representation? It seems to me your "tesselations" are the boundaries of the Platonic solids, at least in the case where the polygons are regular. I guess in general you're considering isohedral polyhedrons.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis true. I think I need to edit the question a bit. Apart from the cube, and using any kind of quads, with the congruence restriction only.

Comment: The only ways to tesselate with congruent regular polygons are the platoinic solids (tetrahedron, cube, octahedron, doedecahedron, icosahedron).

Comment: I *think* that the combination of all faces congruent and all vertices placed on the sphere restricts one to the Platonic solids, but I'm unsure.

Comment: The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome gets pretty close to a generalization with probably minimum distortion. But in order not to digress from the initial question.. I am actually looking for a (rather) well known Diff Geom theorem/remarkable statement that, as a consequence, does not allow such tessellations - it should be well known so that most undergrads recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any trivial quad tessellation that minimizes distortion in this case

As indicated in a comment, a cube is a tesselation of a sphere using squares as the tiles. Not a very interesting/useful tesselation, from a graphics point of view, though, unless the spherical object is very small or you're trying very hard to minimize the number of polygons used.

You can get a a low-distortion quad tesselation by "inflating" a cube to get 6 patches that lie on the sphere. Or, saying it another way, you project the faces of the cube radially onto the sphere. One of the faces of the cube can be represented by the equations $(u,v) \mapsto (u,v,1)$ for $-1 \le u \le 1$ and  $-1 \le v \le 1$ after the radial projection, you get the parametrization
$$
\mathbf x(u,v) = \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 +1}}, 
                       \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 +1}}, 
                       \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 +1}} \right)
$$
for a patch that covers one sixth of the sphere. You tesselate this patch in the obvious way, by making constant-sized steps in $u$ and $v$. The other five faces can be handled similarly, or can be obtained by rotations.

Here's a picture of one patch:

[image: sphere patch]

I don't know if the distortion is minimal, but it seems fairly low, to me.

Patches of this type can also be written in NURBS form (non-uniform rational b-spline), and you may be able to hand these to your graphics subsystem and have it do the tesselation for you.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that quadrilaterals average $90^\circ$ angles.  If four of them meet at every corner, you wont have the required $720^\circ$ deficit to make a closed sphere.  You need eight three-way vertices to get it to close.  This is like the requirement that using hexagons and pentagons you need 12 pentagons for a full sphere.  As one approximation, you can take a spherical cap and choose four points on the bottom circle to identify as "vertices" of your "quadrilateral", but maybe this is too trivial.  You can also inscribe a cube in a sphere and project the edges outward to make a tessellation.  The edges will not be geodesics.  You can then subdivide the squares with quadrilaterals to make a tessellation with more elements.